# App crashing (only on select phones)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a iPhone app I submitted a week ago and all was fine and dandy. Worked like a charm on my phone and my brothers.

However it wasn't till today when I tested it on some of my family's phones when it went haywire. They couldn't do anything and it crashed right after logging in. I even put the version they had on my phone and it worked fine, even with their account. Could this be something to do with the provisioning profile? Different firmwares crashed at different times, if that helps at all.

I am kinda leary because I submitted it to apple with the distribution profile about a week ago. Do you think they are going to have the same issues with crashing? Or does the distribution profile fix my issue?

Just curious because this is my first official app to get reviewed by apple.

Coulton

Comment: You need to post the crash report from a phone that the app is not working on.

Comment: Just a plain 'ole `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Why does this work on one phone but not the others (both on iOS 4.2.1 and both iPhone 3G)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be several different things.

The first one that stands out is what version ios are the phones running that crash or have problems?  If they're pre-version 4.0 you could always download the older SDKs and test on the simulators there and debug.  If they're 4.0+, have you tried testing on the simulator with 4.0, 4.1, 4.2?  Do those handle it fine?

Another thing is, have those phones been running for a while?  If you restart them, and then run your app does it still crash?

In regards to the provisioning profiles, have tried deploying to those other handsets without that?  A good article for that can be found here:  http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution

In terms of Apple finding these crashes, etc..  They might and might not, but regardless of that, I would look at troubleshooting on your own, because if it's a consistent thing with certain handsets, that could reflect poorly in your app reviews, etc...

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking it was something to do with the provisioning profile, because it just started working. Got an email about an hour ago with rejection. This just makes me so mad. I've been working on this for two months and have to wait over a week just to get told NO.

Comment: This whole process just irritates me.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using selectors that are not supported in the older iOS. To resolve, you may have to edit your codes to support the older iOS version.
Otherwise, change your iOS deployment target in your Xcode project to the appropriate version. But first, determine if your family devices are running older iOS and test your project in older simulators to see if it still crashes, you should be able to see the crash reason from the debug console and fix it.
Update your app in the app store after the testing. Good luck.